# What are the forces acting on a swingset that has been rotated?

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics

I'm doing a report for which I need to understand why a twisted swingset like equipment would unravel. A picture is given below:
[image: A object hanging from 2 strings is twisted, and then let go, because of which it ravels and unravels]

I want to understand what the forces are acting, which makes a twisted swingset rotate. When you resolve them, won't they just cancel out?

Comment: Have you thought about the torque due to the forces? Just because net force is $0$ does not mean net torque is $0$. Can you please include in your question why you think the net torque is also $0$?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, for an ideal case, there would be a point that looks like picture 2, where there would be no rotation, all the forces are balanced. However, that is not very physical, since it requires that the ropes holding up the swing perfectly cross, and intersects itself. In an actual swing set, this obviously cannot happen.

Even if it could, this position is unstable. That means that a small change in the position causes a force that pushes the system away from this position. When the swing set is crossed in the middle picture, the lengths of the rope stay the same, and therefore the center of mass of the entire swing set must be higher. The rope is like a pendulum that has swung up. Any small push away from that balanced position causes it to fall back down, into the position on the left. This means that if you built this swing set and tried to set it very close to the ideal position in picture 2, you would still be slightly off (because its impossible), and the swing would fall back, in picture 3.

Comment: Thanks! That helps.